# How can I get pixel precision when placing text with Auto Layout?

Tags: ios, autolayout

When using Auto Layout to position a label, I always get very imprecise results. In the example below, I have aligned the top and left edges of a UILabel to a parent UIView:

[image]

There is empty space on all four sides of the text, but the amount of empty space at the top and bottom is especially horrible. It is very tedious to take screenshots and figure out how many points I would need to offset the constraint's constant value to make the text line up properly. Is there any way to for the UILabel to properly reflect the rendered text in its frame?

Comment: Are you using `NSLayoutConstraint`s?

Comment: equal width and equal height to it's parent

Comment: @CeceXX Yes, I am laying my constraints out programatically. I could be wrong, but I think the problem is because the frame of the UILabel is wrong. The frame is sized according to the rules of the font, rather than what is rendered. I need a way to have the label be trimmed properly, or for autolayout to know how to deal with the UILabel.

Comment: U can use attributed label text and set the line spacing to 0.x, it will make your top and bottom space go away :D hope i rmb correctly

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/SnapKit/Masonry it makes easy to change constrains at runtime, where you can make pixel calcs.

Comment: "There is empty space on all four sides of the text"..You mean spaces in green coloured view?

Comment: Yes, the green part.